# Bootstrap grid displaying column out of row in small screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

How can I display my **Hello-div-2** after **Hello-div-3** in small screen?
Right now the flow is

> **Hello-div-1, Hello-div-2, Hello-div-3, Hello-div-4**.

It should be

> **Hello-div-1, Hello-div-3, Hello-div-2, Hello-div-4.**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-12 bg-primary">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-1</h2>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-success">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light ">Hello-div-2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8 col-12 bg-info">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-3</h2>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-warning">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can't change structure only solution which i can think of is

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-12 bg-primary">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-1</h2>
        </div>
         <!-- hide this in small screen -->
         <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-success">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light ">Hello-div-2</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8 col-12 bg-info">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-3</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- show this in small screen -->
         <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-success">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light ">Hello-div-2</h2>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-warning">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in the same `.row` and use the `.order-` classes...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-12 bg-primary order-0 order-md-0">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-success order-2 order-md-0">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light ">Hello-div-2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-12 bg-info order-1 order-md-0">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-warning order-3 order-md-0">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light">Hello-div-4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/m8sgEDDmp2

Comment: Thanks @Codeply-er  the row should be as it is. can this be done using some media-queries?

Comment: No. You can't change the order of columns that share different flexbox parents (.row). Why do they need to be in different rows?